# ssh source command not found

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I'm getting an error if i do ssh and source an alias command and execute that command,
    saying "command not found". what might be the problem? I have done alias for this command      in remote machine. 
     Thanks in advance

Comment: Show examples of commands you're running.

Answer (score 4):

Log in using a full terminal, and execute bash directly as an interactive login shell with the command you want to run:

```
ssh -t <hostname> bash -lic '<command-or-alias>'
```

This should parse all your aliases and execute the command properly.

Comment: Still gives error Creating ESA backup for node sc-1
/home/backup/sshDemo: line 5: sc-1: command not found
Creating ESA backup for node sc-2
/home/backup/sshDemo: line 5: sc-2: command not found
Creating ESA backup for node pl-1
/home/backup/sshDemo: line 5: pl-1: command not found
Creating ESA backup for node pl-2
/home/backup/sshDemo: line 5: pl-2: command not found

Comment: code #!/bin/bash
 for node in $(grep "^node" /cluster/etc/cluster.conf | awk '{print $4}');
        do
                echo "Creating ESA backup for node ${node}";
                #$ssh  $node bash -lic  "source /etc/profile.d/esa.sh'; esaBackup -b /home/backup/esa/${node}";
                ssh -n $node source /etc/profile.d/esa.sh; esaBackup -b /home/backup/esa/${node};
                #ssh  $node /opt/ESA/ESA/bin/esaBackup -b /home/backup/esa/${node};
        done;

Comment: You are sshing to a host, and then running a script which in turn executes ssh again. The second ssh call doesn't include the options I put in my answer.